# UWP (Universal Windows Platform) Web Service in Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm pretty much new at StackOverflow and UWP. Ive being programming in C# for like 2 years almost but never did UWP before.

Since UWP doesn't admit database direct connection, I was trying to create a web service. Now, I being playing with the "Hello World" by default in Visual Studio´s web service file and trying to make a reference in the UWP app but I cant make a simple textblock to display what the method does in the web service (returns a "Hello World"). So here is the code:

1) Web Service by default

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/",Name ="Transfer")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
}
```

2) UWP App

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace UWPWSApp
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            WebServiceTransfer.TransferSoapClient tsc = new WebServiceTransfer.TransferSoapClient();
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem gets here, because I see a "HelloWorldAsync()", here is a screen:

[ScreenCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMXW4.png)

I've already tried with the Async method but doesn't seem to be the one that displays "Hello World".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `tsc.HelloWorldAsync()` method is a asynchronous method:

[image]

When you use this method, you will need use **await** operator, and you must include the "async" keyword in the method declaration in which you use this await operator.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

This is constructor of MainPage, it initializes a new instance of the MainPage class. It's not a method and constructor can't not be used with await operator, so you can for example using the [Loaded event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) here.

Secondly, I saw your code like this:

```
textBlock.Text = tsc.HelloWorldAsync();
```

The `Text` property of a `TextBlock` should be a string, but `tsc.HelloWorldAsync()` returns a `HelloWorldResponse` type as you can see in my picture up, the type here is not match, so you can code it like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebServiceTransfer.TransferSoapClient tsc = new WebServiceTransfer.TransferSoapClient();
    var response = await tsc.HelloWorldAsync();
    textBlock.Text = response.Body.HelloWorldResult;
}
```